# Remap key based on its position on the keyboard, not on the character a keypress triggers

Tags: autohotkey

I have an english keyboard set to german. So instead of qwerty I am using qwertz. When I switch my keyboard back to english, I want to have the default english keyboard, except for the characters y and z, because I am so used to typing these in german that I always get them mixed up when I change the layout.
So I am looking for a script like:

```
If keypress is third row, 7th key:
   Change output to z
If keypress is fifth row, 2nd key:
   Change output to y
```

An alternative would be to make the change conditional on the english language layout:

```
If keyboard-layout is english:
   if keypress is y:
      Change output to z
   if keypress is z:
      Change output to y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remap based off scan codes:

```
SC15::z
SC2C::y
```

Scan codes don't depend on what keyboard layout you have, or whatever.
Also please note that you may not have these same scan codes as I have.
You can find our scan codes yourself with e.g. `GetKeySC()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKey.htm)</sup> or by [using the keyhistory](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: 0x464e, what a bright idea! I get the same scan codes, however the remapping only works if I use the virtual key codes: `VK5A` for `z` and `VK59` for `y`.

Comment: Hmm, worked fine for me when I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#If (GetKeyboardLanguage(WinActive("A")) = 0x0409) ; english (german = 0x0407)

    z::y
    y::z
    
#If
            
GetKeyboardLanguage(_hWnd=0){
    if !_hWnd
        ThreadId=0
    else
        if !ThreadId := DllCall("user32.dll\GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", _hWnd, "UInt", 0, "UInt")
            return false    
    if !KBLayout := DllCall("user32.dll\GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadId, "UInt")
        return false    
    return KBLayout & 0xFFFF
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/116538-detect-which-language-is-currently-on/#entry672236

Comment: Works, however, 0x464e's answer is shorter, so I accepted that. Thank you for putting in the work